# Pointer "does not have a type" when compiling?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, dynamic

Here is my code.

```
struct player
   {
   char* name;
   int* id;
   id = new int[5];
   };
```

When I compile, it says "error: 'id' does not name a type", pointing to the line the line where the pointer is allocated space for 5 ints.

Don't ask my why I need an array of integers; it's for a class project and is required (our teacher likes making us do unnecessary things to give us practice).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Except that this syntax is not the correct syntax for an inline initializer.

Comment: Todays method would be `std::array<int, 5> id`, your teacher is still using techniques that literally belong in the 20th century.

Comment: What is an inline initializer?

Comment: @AndreyT: d'oh, of course...

Answer (score 3):

How did you come up with this code and what do you expect it to do?

This line

```
id = new int[5];
```

looks like an expression statement. What is this statement doing inside a class definition? Expression statements belong inside functions and nowhere else. You are not allowed to inject them into class definitions. They don't belong there. This what the compiler is telling you by that error message: it expects a type name for the next member declaration, and instead it sees something that begins with `id` and generally makes no sense in that context.

If you tried to use an inline initializer, the proper syntax would be

```
struct player
{
  char* name;
  int* id = new int[5];
};
```

The initializer has to be a part of the declaration, as shown above. You can't just split it into a separate statement, stuff it into the class definition and expect the compiler to figure out what you meant.

Otherwise (i.e. if you were not trying to use an inline initializer), you'd have to initialize `player::id` in the constructor

```
struct player
{
  char* name;
  int* id;

  player(): id(new int[5]) 
    {}
  ...
};
```

(The proper implementation of such class would require following the Rule of Three, of course.)

Or you can initialize it from outside. What is the right approach here depends on your intent.

Comment: Although I'd favor this in the possible absence of `std::array`, unless the OP explicitly states that destruction is to be handled outside `player's` dtor, I suggest you add the appropriate implementation.

Comment: @thokra: No. The OP clearly stated that this is a "training" assignment. While I can't entirely guess what they were trying to learn, the original syntax suggests an allocated independent array referred by a pointer from a struct. Meanwhile, an `std::array` would implement an "embedded" array, which is a completely different thing. `std::array` is just a bit more civilized  equivalent of `int id[5]`. Since they did not use `int id[5]` from the start, I presume that `std::array` is also not the "appropriate implementation".

Comment: @thokra: Most likely it is implied that in general case the array size will not be specified by a compile time constant, which is why they are allocating it at run-time. This would immediately exclude `std::array` from consideration. In that case the proper replacement for a raw array would be `std::vector`, not `std::array`. However, in any case, I don't want to clutter my answer with guesses based on desperately lacking information. I just answer the question itself directly.

Comment: You're correct in regards to `std::array`. My bad, wasn't thinking. However, I was talking about putting the appropriate implementation of the type's destructor in there, i.e. a destructor invoking `delete[]`. I don't think this is a bad guess to make. But again, the OP didn't state that cleanup is supposed to be handled by the type itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
struct player
   {
   char *name;
   int id[5];
   };
```

Comment: I would, but must declare all arrays using dynamic allocation for this program. Thus, I can't declare the array that way.

Comment: @user1362548: See AndreyT's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can't type line of codes in struct.
You only define variables. struct expected that you are defining a new variable. therefore, the error says id is not a type definition like int and char.

you can do this initialisation out of the struct if you insist on using pointer.

```
a.id = new int[5];
```

or

inside like the other answer:

```
struct player
{
   char *name;
   int id[5];
};
```

Comment: You can't have _statements_ in a struct.

Comment: Also, this is not initialization. By the time you can assign a value to a member of an instance of `player`, the `int*` will have already been "garbage" initialized, i.e. will have an undefined value.